# Compose multiplatform drag&drop to copy item to another list

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I have list filled with users, and i want to somehow copy specific user to another list by dragging him in it.
I'v founded several examples about reordering lists, but it seems to me it's not that i'm loocking for

If needed i can post my code here, but i think it's more about finding global sollution